Next js theme changes to dark mode on page reload
I am trying to implement theme changing feature in my next JS 14 app . Now I can change the app theme by clicking on the toggle icon. But if i change my theme to light and reload the page, the theme setting to dark i am using next-themes for this. I have also checked the localstorage as well, on page reload the value of theme key is changed to dark.
Layout.tsx file :
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Sidebar from "@/components/navigationBar/Sidebar";
import { Providers } from "./providers";
import MobileSidebar from "@/components/navigationBar/MobileSidebar";



const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Providers>
          <div className="sm:block hidden">
            <Sidebar />
          </div>
          <div className="sm:hidden block">
            <MobileSidebar />
          </div>
          {children}
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


Provider.tsx:
"use client";
import * as React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes";

type Props = {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
};

export function Providers({ children }: Props) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider attribute="class" defaultTheme="system" enableSystem>
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}


Sidebar component :
"use client";
import { sidebarLinks } from "@/constants/sidebarLinks";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { TbCurrencyTaka } from "react-icons/tb";
import Icon from "../Icon";
import { useTheme } from "next-themes";

const Sidebar = () => {
  const [toggleSidebar, setToggleSidebar] = useState(false);
  const { setTheme, resolvedTheme } = useTheme();

 
  return (
    <div
      className={`dark:bg-slate-900 bg-[#ffffff] h-screen py-4 flex justify-between flex-col transition-all ease-in duration-300 ${
        toggleSidebar ? "w-[249px] ps-4" : "w-[58px] items-center"
      }`}
    >
     

      <div
        className={`flex justify-start cursor-pointer bg-[#1E293B]  text-white font-medium transition-all ease-in duration-300 
      ${
        toggleSidebar
          ? "h-[41px] w-[233px] rounded-s items-center ps-3"
          : "h-[43px] w-[40px] rounded items-center ps-2"
      }`}
        onClick={() =>
          resolvedTheme == "dark" ? setTheme("light") : setTheme("dark")
        }
      >
        <div>
          {resolvedTheme === "light" ? (
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <Icon
                iconName={sidebarLinks.themes.dark.icon}
                iconcontainerCls=""
                iconCls={`text-gray-50 h-[21px] w-[22px]`}
              />
              <span
                className={`${
                  toggleSidebar
                    ? "font-normal ps-[0.7rem] whitespace-nowrap "
                    : "hidden"
                }`}
              >
                {sidebarLinks.themes.dark.title}
              </span>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <Icon
                iconName={sidebarLinks.themes.light.icon}
                iconcontainerCls=""
                iconCls={`text-gray-50 h-[21px] w-[22px]`}
              />
              <span
                className={`${
                  toggleSidebar
                    ? "font-normal ps-[0.7rem] whitespace-nowrap cursor-pointer"
                    : "hidden"
                }`}
              >
                {sidebarLinks.themes.light.title}
              </span>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;


I would like to keep the selected theme on reload . I tried creating another localstorage key but it didnt work.
